# Change attribute when currency is changed

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, ce-1.9.2.2, multicurrency

I want to change the attribute when currency is changed on product view page. For example when someone selects $ it changes to US sizes.

Comment: Are want to use different attribute on basic currency.Or use  want use same attribute different value?

Comment: @AmitBera Same attribute different value